# Regex - match several nested values in JSON both parent and sibling

Tags: json, regex

So i have a json that looks like the one below. The version is simplified and the JSON in production has tons of items in it. What I'm looking to extract is the "`id"` of the object that has items in`"exclusions"` list as well as the `"id"` of the elements inside the exclusion list, i.e. in this case those would be `5229`, `3486`, `3489`

```
    {
      "id": 5229,
      "Type": B,
      "exclusions": [
          {
            "id": 3486,
            "desig": "A",
            "price": 101,

          },
          {
             "id": 3489,
             "desig": "A",
             "price": 101,
          }]},

    {
      "id": 5239,
      "Type": B,
      "exclusions": []
    }
```

Comment: Use JSON parser

Comment: i need a regex expression for the regex extractor in Jmeter

Comment: You could try to use this: https://jsbin.com/dijuboyitu/edit?js,console , but it's not so reliable as using JSON parser

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*?"id": (\d+).*?("exclusions": \[.*?|"desig").*?{`. [Test Online](https://regex101.com/r/vzUHk7/1)